# JavaFX VBox Layout

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, javafx

I have written a code using VBox as layout. I want the button to appear at the top row, and then draw 2 horizontal lines which should be at y=200 and 300 in the 400x400 scene. But the output shows the lines at different co-ordinates I give it.

I understand this is because of the Layout I am defining. My question is this:

1) Can I somehow draw lines at true co-ordinates keeping the same layout?

2) If not, which javafx layout would be best for this operation?

3) Assuming there is a MenuBar instead of that button, then which layout would be most suitable?

```
package practise;

import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Practise extends Application {

    private int c = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        VBox root = new VBox();

        Group group = new Group();

        final Line l1 = new Line(0,200,400,200);      
        final Line l2 = new Line(0,300,400,300);      

        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
                }
            }
        );


        l1.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
        l1.setStrokeWidth(2);
        l1.setLayoutX(0);
        l1.setLayoutY(0);
        l2.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
        l2.setStrokeWidth(2);
        l2.setLayoutX(0);
        l2.setLayoutY(0);

        group.getChildren().add(l1);
        group.getChildren().add(l2);
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        root.getChildren().add(group);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.WHITE);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes this is possible. Setting [the `managed` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#managedProperty) to `false` results in the parent not layouting the child. This won't make the next node being positioned below the line though.

```
Button btn = new Button();
VBox root = new VBox();

final Line l1 = new Line(0, 200, 400, 200);
final Line l2 = new Line(0, 300, 400, 300);

l1.setManaged(false);
l2.setManaged(false);

btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
});

l1.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
l1.setStrokeWidth(2);
l2.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
l2.setStrokeWidth(2);
root.getChildren().addAll(btn, l1, l2, rect);
```

2)

#### `GridPane`

allows to specify constraints on the row size.

```
Button btn = new Button();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(400, 10);
GridPane root = new GridPane();
root.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(200));

final Line l1 = new Line(0, 0, 400, 0);

btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
});

l1.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
l1.setStrokeWidth(2);
root.addColumn(0, btn, l1, rect);
```

#### `SplitPane`

could do this too with some adjustments.

```
Button btn = new Button();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(400, 10);

// wrap contents in resizeable Nodes
SplitPane root = new SplitPane(new Pane(btn), new Pane(rect));

// place divider in the middle
root.setDividerPositions(0.5);
root.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
root.getStyleClass().add("line-split");
root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

root.skinProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // don't allow resizing
    newValue.getNode().lookupAll(".split-pane-divider").stream().forEach(divider -> divider.setDisable(true));
});

btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
});
```

CSS

```
.line-split .split-pane-divider {
    -fx-min-height: 2;
    -fx-max-height: 2;
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}
```

3) `MenuBar` is a `Node` too. There seems to be no reason to treat it differently to a `Button`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want set absolute positions you should use an AnchorPane.
Only change VBox to AnchorPane and will work.